# How to freeze entire SVN repository to make it read-only

Tags: svn

Can't find an answer to my exact question. We migrated to a different source control system and want to keep a read-only snapshot of the entire repository. No one should be able to commit any changes anywhere. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @nvl why would this be on superuser?  source control is primarily a programmer tool, not a regular computer user's tool...

Comment: @Nathan: i was confused. resolved now.

Comment: @Nathan DeWitt: You're right... it belongs on ServerFault, because it's a server configuration issue.

Comment: @Powerlord: I still disagree.  Setting up a programmer's tool is more likely a task assigned to a programmer than it is assigned to a server admin.  I know that in all my jobs there has never been a server admin that says "oh hey, let me set up your source control software for you". In fact, the opposite happens. "It's a programmer tool, you do it."

Comment: @Nathan DeWitt: Here, I'll quote the part of the original post that singles it out as the server admin's job: "We migrated to a different source control system"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just update your [authz file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to

```
# give everyone read-only access to the entire repository
[reponame:/]
* = r
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you also need your authz file to be configured in the *http.conf* file. Not sure what the default is otherwise - read/write for everyone, I assume?

Comment: This is only helpful if you're using Apache or svnserve. eg. I use svn+ssh and this doesn't apply.

Comment: this works only if the authz-file allows read-only access to anyody anyhow; if you have private branches, this might make them available to the public. so take care.

Comment: To do it for all repositories, use `[/]`

Answer (score 37):

You can create a hook to do this:

`repository/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "No more commit here - this is an archive branch" 1>&2
exit 1
```

Notes that log messages must be redirect to **/dev/stderr** (that's the meaning of the **1>&2**).

Comment: Thanks, this is especially useful when you aren't using an own SVN server but instead a simple folder on a Windows Server (e.g. created using the "Create Repository Here" function of TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Note, the error message doesn't display quite right unless its sent to the `stderr`. Suggest to change echo to `echo "No more commit here - this is an archive branch" | tee /dev/stderr`

Comment: @Romuald Brunet, could you edit your pose to add ` >&2` to the echo?

Comment: To those reading @TimMeyer's comment, beware that using a file:/// SVN "server" is NOT recommended. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html for reference:
_Do not be seduced by the simple idea of having all of your users access a repository directly via file:// URLs. Even if the repository is readily available to everyone via a network share, this is a bad idea. It removes any layers of protection between the users and the repository: users can accidentally (or intentionally) corrupt the repository database,..._

Comment: @BaptisteMathus I second that, we have (finally) switched over to a SVN server in the meantime ;-)

Comment: In my case, I prefer this approach because when a commit attempt is rejected, a useful message can be printed telling the user where to go to find the read-write version of the repository.

Comment: This is a good solution. It can be improved by using the **start-commit** hook instead. That hooks runs earlier than the pre-commit hook. From the manual: "The start-commit hook is run before the commit transaction is even created. It is typically used to decide whether the user has commit privileges at all." and "Common uses: Access control (e.g., temporarily lock out commits for some reason)".

Answer (score 2):

Or access for whole server modify svnserve.conf on line auth-access = none|read|write,
then restart server.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can also use the `svnadmin freeze` [command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.freeze.html) to freeze write access to the repository while running another process (e.g. whilst backing up the repository).